# Set ListPreference to be unselected at default

Tags: android-preferences

I need to build an app based on another app. In my PreferenceScreen I have 2 ListPreference objects. The second is dependant on the first and disabled untill the first is selected (still need to figure that one out)

I want to set the first ListPreference to not be selected at the first launch of my App. I can do this by not assigning a key, but will I be able te retrieve values for the ListPreference without its key? Is there another way of doing this?

I can reach the Preferences in my PreferenceScreen by using the following code if the ListPreferce doesn't have a key :

```
ListPreference locationList = (ListPreference)getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter().getItem(1);'
```

I did this for every Preference I need a reference to. Would be better to use SharedPreference?

Answer (score 0):

In your Preferences XML you can use the following on your second `ListPreference`:

```
android:dependency="key_of_first_listpreference"
android:enabled="false"
```

And then in your code, you can add a listener so that when the first listpreference is selected you can populate the second listpreference and enable it like so:

```
final PreferenceScreen prefsRoot = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen();
final ListPreference lpFirst  = (ListPreference) prefsRoot.findPreference("first_listpref_key");
final ListPreference lpSecond = (ListPreference) prefsRoot.findPreference("second_listpref_key");

lpFirst.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){
    @Override public boolean onPreferenceChange ( Preference preference, Object newValue )
    {
        lpSecond.setEntries(R.array.bg_colors);
        lpSecond.setEntryValues(R.array.bg_color_values);
        lpSecond.setEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works on the logic that the Second Preference can only be editable right after the First preference is set. I don't think that's enough - you can set the First preference's value beforehand and you should still be able to select the Second preference.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for so late answer, hope it will help to someone.

You dont need to remove key from your ListPreference for to set ListPreference unselected by default. Just remove the preference value with the code and the ListPreference will not have selected value :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // next 2 lines should be right after onCreate()
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.edit().remove("your_preference_key").commit();

    // all your other code...
}
```

It should be commit(), with apply() it will not work (or will work only sometimes).